# BulkAPI 2.0 Import PricebookEntries via Postman getting this error:STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED:Before creating a custom price, create a standard price

Tags: salesforcedx, pricebook, pricebookentry, postman, bulk-api-v2

I have setup the Postman requests to talk to the salesforce BulkAPI 2.0 because the dataLoader doesn't work (MacBook M1). The import of the pricebookentries fail at a point because when I import the PricebookEntries like this:

```
IsActive,UseStandardPrice,Product2Id,CurrencyIsoCode,Pricebook2Id
TRUE,763.87,01t0E00000A74LWQAZ,EUR,01s0E000002jOOUQA2
...
TRUE,864.71,01t0E00000A74LXQAZ,EUR,01s0E000002jOOUQA2
```

I get an error:

```
"sf__Id","sf__Error",IsActive,UnitPrice,Product2Id,CurrencyIsoCode,Pricebook2Id
"","STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED:Before creating a custom price, create a standard price.:--","true","763.87",
```

Can anyone give me a hint where I might missed something?

Many thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured the Standard Price is referring to the standard price-book which needs to be defined before any other price-book.